# cambiar disabled td en una tabla con x-editable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Deseo poder hacer una tabla que me disable los `td` dependiendo del select option que yo seleccione.

Ejemplo: Si selecciono la Madera1 el primer y segundo `td` quedan habilitados y el tercero disableado con el boton enabled `td` al lado.

Pero si seleciono la Madera2 el segundo y tercero quedan habilitados(quitando el boton enabled `td`) y el primer `td` queda disableado con el boton enabled `td`.

Y si selecciono la Madera3 solo el primer `td` queda habilitado y el segundo con el tercero disableados con el boton enabled `td` al lado.

```js
$('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.task',
        title: 'task',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
         type: 'text',
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        },  
        success: function(response) {
  
           $(this).parent().find(".Item").click();
        }
    });
    var ITEM = [];
    $.each({
        "Item1": "Item1",
        "Item2": "Item2",
        "Item3": "Item3",
        "Item4": "Item4"
    }, function(k, v) {
        ITEM.push({
            value: k,
            text: v
        });
    });
    
    $('#table').editable({
        container: 'body',
        selector: 'td.Item',
        title: 'Item',
        type: "POST",
        showbuttons: false,
        source: ITEM,
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'Empty!';
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
             <small>Clasificacion Producto</small>
        <select class="form-group browser-default custom-select" id="clasificacion">
           <option selected disabled>.::Clasificacion::.</option>
           <option value="Madera1">Madera1</option>
           <option value="Madera2">Madera2</option>
           <option value="Madera3">Madera3</option>
              
                        </select>
                      </div>
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">001</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item2</td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-name="task" data-disabled="true" class="task" data-type="text">002</td>
  <td data-name="Item" data-disabled="true" class="Item" data-type="select">Item1</td>
  <td>  <button id="enable" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">enable td</button></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">003</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item3</td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

He intentado hacerlo con un switch.

```
<script>
$("#clasificacion").change(function() {

        var valor = $(this).val(); // Capturamos el valor del select
        var texto = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); // Capturamos el texto del option seleccionado

  switch (texto) {
          case 'Madera1':
            var celdas = $('#table tbody > tr').find('td'); //ENCONTRAMOS EL TD
            break;
          case 'Madera2':
            var celdas = $('#table tbody > tr').find('td'); //ENCONTRAMOS EL TD
            break;
          case 'Madera3':
            var celdas = $('#table tbody > tr').find('td'); //ENCONTRAMOS EL TD
            break;

    });
</script>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien. Saludos
PD: Tambien si es posible que el boton enabled `td` pueda quitarle el disabled de ese `td`.

Comment: En el `switch` no has intentado nada.

Comment: @alanfcm agrego lo poco que tenia en mi switch donde encuentro el TD

Comment: Si tu tabla es estática, podrías agregarle un identificador a cada `fila(tr)` y en base a eso ir cumpliendo las condiciones dentro del `switch`

Comment: @Ricardo Si mi taba es estatica, puedo agregarle un identificador y aplicar `.data('disabled', false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinceramente nunca había trabajado con `x-editable`, el código hace lo que tu necesitas, tiene algunos detalles que tu mismo podrías corregir:

```js
$('#table').editable({
    container: 'body',
    selector: 'td.task',
    title: 'task',
    type: "POST",
    showbuttons: false,
    type: 'text',
    validate: function(value) {
        if ($.trim(value) == '') {
            return 'Empty!';
        }
    },
    success: function(response) {

        $(this).parent().find(".Item").click();
    }
});
var ITEM = [];
$.each({
    "Item1": "Item1",
    "Item2": "Item2",
    "Item3": "Item3",
    "Item4": "Item4"
}, function(k, v) {
    ITEM.push({
        value: k,
        text: v
    });
});

$('#table').editable({
    container: 'body',
    selector: 'td.Item',
    title: 'Item',
    type: "POST",
    showbuttons: false,
    source: ITEM,
    validate: function(value) {
        if ($.trim(value) == '') {
            return 'Empty!';
        }
    }
});


$("#clasificacion").change(function() {

    var valor = $(this).val(); // Capturamos el valor del select
    var texto = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    var opt1 = $(".opt1").data('blocked');
    var opt2 = $(".opt2").data('blocked');
    var opt3 = $(".opt3").data('blocked'); // Capturamos el texto del option seleccionado
    $(".btntd").remove();

    if (opt1 == true) {
        $(".opt1 > td.task").editable('option', 'disabled', false);
        $(".opt1 > td.Item").editable('option', 'disabled', false);
    }
    if (opt2 == true) {
        $(".opt2 > td.task").editable('option', 'disabled', false);
        $(".opt2 > td.Item").editable('option', 'disabled', false);
    }
    if (opt3 == true) {
        $(".opt3 > td.task").editable('option', 'disabled', false);
        $(".opt3 > td.Item").editable('option', 'disabled', false);

    }



    switch (texto) {
        case 'Madera1':
            //ENCONTRAMOS EL TD
            $(".opt3 > td.task").editable('option', 'disabled', true);
            $(".opt3 > td.Item").editable('option', 'disabled', true);
            $(".opt3").data('blocked', true);
            $(".opt2").data('blocked', false);
            $(".opt1").data('blocked', false);
            $(".opt3").append("<td class='btntd'><button id='enable' data-val='opt3' class='btn btn-sm btn-default'>enable td</button></td>");
            break;
        case 'Madera2':
            $(".opt1 > td.task").editable('option', 'disabled', true);
            $(".opt1 > td.Item").editable('option', 'disabled', true);
            $(".opt1").data('blocked', true);
            $(".opt2").data('blocked', false);
            $(".opt3").data('blocked', false);
            $(".opt1").append("<td class='btntd'><button id='enable' data-val='opt1' class='btn btn-sm btn-default'>enable td</button></td>"); //ENCONTRAMOS EL TD
            break;
        case 'Madera3':
            $(".opt2 > td.task").editable('option', 'disabled', true);
            $(".opt2 > td.Item").editable('option', 'disabled', true);
            $(".opt2").data('blocked', true);
            $(".opt1").data('blocked', false);
            $(".opt2").append("<td class='btntd'><button id='enable' data-val='opt2' class='btn btn-sm btn-default'>enable td</button></td>");
            $(".opt3 > td.task").editable('option', 'disabled', true);
            $(".opt3 > td.Item").editable('option', 'disabled', true);
            $(".opt3").data('blocked', true);

            $(".opt3").append("<td class='btntd'><button id='enable' data-val='opt3' class='btn btn-sm btn-default'>enable td</button></td>"); //ENCONTRAMOS EL TD
            break;
    }

});
$("#table > tbody > tr").on('click', "#enable", function(event) {
    var valor = $(this).data("val");

    $("." + valor + " > td.task").editable('option', 'disabled', false);
    $("." + valor + " > td.Item").editable('option', 'disabled', false);

});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <small>Clasificacion Producto</small>
   <select class="form-group browser-default custom-select" id="clasificacion">
      <option selected disabled>.::Clasificacion::.</option>
      <option value="opt1">Madera1</option>
      <option value="opt2">Madera2</option>
      <option value="opt3">Madera3</option>
   </select>
</div>
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>Task</th>
         <th>Item</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="opt1">
         <td>1</td>
         <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">001</td>
         <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="opt2">
         <td>2</td>
         <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">002</td>
         <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="opt3">
         <td>3</td>
         <td data-name="task" class="task" data-type="text">003</td>
         <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="select">Item3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Básicamente lo que hace, es que dependiendo del valor que selecciones en tu `select` va tomando las acciones en la tabla, habilita y des habilita los campos, ademas de la funcionalidad del botón para habilitar la fila completa.

Puedes simplificarlo y mejorarlo como mejor te convenga, esto solo es un ejemplo de como lo puedes hacer basándote en el `switch`.

Espero y te sirva, Saludos.